# Retrieving SAMAccountName from ActiveDirectory in VB.Net

Tags: active-directory, visual-studio-2017, user-profile

In my application I have an 'Audience selector' which lets you search groups and users in Active Directory. The groups bit works a treat, but I'm having an issue with the users bit.

Here is my code:

```
Public Function GetGroups() As List(Of String)
    Dim objADAM As DirectoryEntry                   ' Binding object.
    Dim objGroupEntry As DirectoryEntry             ' Group Results.
    Dim objSearchADAM As DirectorySearcher          ' Search object.
    Dim objSearchResults As SearchResultCollection  ' Results collection.
    Dim strPath As String                           ' Binding path.
    Dim result As New List(Of String)

    strPath = "LDAP://MYDOMAINCONTROLLER.MYDOMAIN"
        objADAM = New DirectoryEntry(strPath)
        objADAM.RefreshCache()

    Try
        objSearchADAM = New DirectorySearcher(objADAM)
        objSearchADAM.Filter = "(&(objectClass=" & AudienceSelector.searchtype.Text & ")(cn=" & AudienceSelector.TextBox1.Text & "))"
        objSearchADAM.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
        If AudienceSelector.searchtype.Text = "user" Then
            objSearchADAM.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName")
        End If
        objSearchResults = objSearchADAM.FindAll()
    Catch e As Exception
    End Try

    Try
        If objSearchResults.Count <> 0 Then
            Dim objResult As SearchResult
            For Each objResult In objSearchResults
                objGroupEntry = objResult.GetDirectoryEntry
                result.Add(objGroupEntry.Name)
            Next objResult
        End If
    Catch e As Exception
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

So if AudienceSelector.searchtype = user, the list of users is returned but I get the friendly name and I need the SAMAccountName. 
So instead of 'john.smith' i'm getting back 'John Smith'.

I've had a search around and tried adding in the PropertiesToLoad bit to bring in the SAMAcountName, but it just gives me the friendly name everytime.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help :-D

Answer (score 0):

I had to grab the propery rather that the objGroupEntry.Name.

A simple if statement later and this...

```
 Dim thisuserSAN As String = objGroupEntry.Properties("SamAccountName").Value.ToString.ToLower
                    result.Add(thisuserSAN)
```

... did the trick :)